# Make windows icon blink on taskbar

Tags: windows, win32gui

We can SetForegroundWindow for a window.

Is there a function to make its icon blinking a number of times on taskbar ?

I have tried things like SetActiveWindow and ShowWindow, to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-flashwindow

Remarks
Flashing a window means changing the appearance of its caption bar as if the window were changing from inactive to active status, or vice versa. (An inactive caption bar changes to an active caption bar; an active caption bar changes to an inactive caption bar.)

Typically, a window is flashed to inform the user that the window requires attention but that it does not currently have the keyboard focus.

The FlashWindow function flashes the window only once; for repeated flashing, the application should create a system timer.

Comment: Yes, this is the function the OP is looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just for info, FlashWindowEx allows to flash window multiple times.